# Java - Returning variable type of object through the same variable

Tags: java, object, return, variable-types

So I have a class `public abstract class Value<?>`

Then I have 2 different subclasses `public class StringV extends Value<String>` and  `public class IntegerV extends Value<Integer>`

I'm using a visitor to go through those classes and return a `Value<?>` type object through it.

This visitor goes through an arraylist of objects and returns either a `StringV` or a `IntegerV` object, I'm trying to implement a method that goes through that arraylist and returns a new object of the respective class. This is what I have implemented, but obviously it doesn't work.

```
public Value<?> visitSequence(Sequence c) {
    Value<?> result;
    int sequence_size = c.size();
    for (int i=0; i<sequence_size; i++) {
        result = c.get(i).accept(this);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there any way of returning a variable type of objects through the same variable? Or is there any other way I can accomplish this?

Part of the Sequence class

```
public class Sequence extends Expression implements Visitable {

  List<Value> _values = null;

  public Sequence() {
    _values = new ArrayList<Value>();
  }

  public Value get(int ix) {
    return _values.get(ix);
  }


   public Value<?> accept(Visitor v) {
      return v.visitSequence(this);}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `c.get(i)` is gonna return you an `Object`. use bounded types in `List` type parameters

Comment: try to change your parameter from `List c` to `List<Value<?>> c`.

Comment: @msgala c is already a list of objects of the type Value, either StringV or IntegerV, so I just want to return the last object of this specific list

Comment: so you want to know the Object will be on the last index?

Comment: @msagala I think I explained myself bad and the slightly modified bit of code I put here only cause confusion, Ive corrected it now. What I have is a object Sequence which contains an arraylist of  `Value` objects I want to iterate through the list with the visitor and then return the last object of the arraylist that is inside the Sequence object.

Comment: @spacing What is the return type of `accept()`? I mean, that'd be a good starting point for the type you should use.

Comment: @JasonC accept returns a `Value<?>`

Comment: @spacing Then what's the problem? Nothing appears wrong with your syntax.

Comment: Why are you reassigning `result` in a loop?

Comment: @shmosel accept goes through the Sequence arraylist and evaluates each of the objects (the visitor is a evaluation visitor). Then I want to return the evaluation of the last object of the list but without evaluating the same object 2 times, hence why I am storing the result in a variable so I can return the result of the last evaluation without doing it twice

Comment: @JasonC I get compiler error `EvaluatorVisitor.java:197: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Value<?>
      result = c.get(i).accept(this);`

Comment: Then `accept()` is not declared as returning a `Value<?>` like you say, it's declared as returning an `Object`, so you'll either have to deal with `Object`, or cast the returned object to a `Value<?>`. Please show us some more about this `Sequence`, since it's not part of the JDK we can't really know what you're talking about here or what the problem is.

Comment: @JasonC added the relevant part of the sequence class

Comment: Yes. All these classes implement Visitable.

Comment: Show us `Value.accept()`.

Comment: @spacing This still doesn't make sense. `Sequence#get` returns a `Value`, so now we need `Value#accept`. If you want help don't make us pull teeth for things like the compiler error, function declarations, and other info. I mean, your error directly involves `result = c.get(i).accept(this)` so the *first* thing you should have shown us is enough to know what that line is doing and what the error was.

Comment: @shmosel `public abstract Value<?> accept(Visitor v);`

Comment: Ok look. Go to http://ideone.com. Get enough code in there that you can reproduce the same compiler error. Then share the link or paste the code here.